# How to preselect an <option> contextually?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There are many instances of class .fare in my html. Therefore I am implementing the solution contextually. For some fares, I want to automatically pick the second value (All fare) on the .fare options list and disable the selection box.

The options are:
  options_fare = "Select a fare"All fare""

However, when I tried the following code, it stay on option 1 (Select a fare).

```
$contextualDiv.children('.fare').html(options_fare);
$contextualDiv.children('.fare option:eq(1)').attr('disabled', false).prop('selected', true).trigger('change');
    }
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your:

`$contextualDiv.children('.fare option:eq(1)')`

to

`$contextualDiv.children('.fare').children('option:eq(1)')`

or

`$contextualDiv.find('.fare option:eq(1)')`

The reason why `children` is not working for your cause because `children` only looks at first level children and not the children of childrens to do a deep search use `find` instead.

[working example](https://jsfiddle.net/gb2945kL/)

Comment: This is a great answer. Thanks!

Comment: A follow up question. When I try to post using the selection, the post request doesn't pick up the selected value. Do you know if I need to do something else to let the post request grab the selection?

Comment: I am pretty sure `$contextualDiv.children('.fare').val()` or `$('.fare').val()` will return the selected value unless there is something else going on

Comment: I thought trigger('change') mimics as if the user selected the option?

Comment: yes it does even if  `change` event has been trigger in the `option` element, `change` event in the select will trigger. unless there is something different going on